# Packer how to connect to Debian genericcloud image

Tags: cloud, ssh-keys, packer

is there any way that packer can connect to Debian `genericcloud` image? We are not using cloud-init, rather we are using packer to create our own image template for our private cloud. Using the iso and build an image template works straight forward.

The `nocloud` image allows root login without a password. Unfortunately ssh port 22 is commented in `sshd_config`, so ssh fails until it is commented out manually, which makes the automation process impossible.

Is there any way that packer can inject the temporary pub key to the `genericcloud` image and connect to it for further modifications?

I tried to use https://github.com/ivoronin/packer-plugin-sshkey but I am not quite sure how should it work, the process stuck at `Waiting for SSH to become available...` and breaks after the `ssh_wait_timeout` is over.

Thanks

Comment: Your options are basically SSH or cloud-init for provisioning the image during Packer execution. If you can do neither, then you are probably in a difficult position.

Comment: Thanks Matt, unfortunately Ganeti doesn't support cloud-init as datasource. It seems we have to keep our setup for now and create our images with packer from iso.

Comment: The other workaround would be to fetch the Debian cloud image and setup a user with `guestfisch` to enable packer to connect to it over ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way, took couple of hours to figure out this.

When using qemu plugin you can specify `cd_files` and `cd_label` to run `cloud-init` inside this machine, but there is important thing. `cd_label` should be exactly `"CIDATA"` with capital letters, also you should pass to cd_files **exactly** two files `user-data` and `meta-data`.

Without this `cloud-init` wouldn't understand you.

There is example directory for you with files content:
`$ ls -1`

```
config.pkr.hcl
meta-data
packer_key
packer_key.pub
user-data
```

`packer_key` is newly generated rsa ssh key file via `ssh-keygen` without password and `packer_key.pub` it's public part

`$ cat meta-data`

```
#cloud-config
```

`$ cat user-data`

```
#cloud-config
users:
- name: root
  ssh_authorized_keys:
    - "here_is_content_of_packer_key.pub"
```

`$ cat config.pkr.hcl`

```
packer {
  required_plugins {
    qemu = {
      version = "~> 1"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/qemu"
    }
  }
}

source "qemu" "example" {
  accelerator               = "kvm"
  boot_command              = []
  disk_compression          = true
  disk_interface            = "virtio"
  disk_image                = true
  disk_size                 = "10000M"
  boot_wait                 = "2s"
  vm_name                   = "debian-genericcloud-amd64-packer.qcow2"
  format                    = "qcow2"
  headless                  = "false"
  iso_checksum              = "sha512:49cbcfdb3d5401e8c731d33211cff5e1ef884f179a936c7378eeab00c582ace45dd7154ac9e4c059f1bd6c7ae2ce805879cb381a12a1cc493e3a58c847e134c7"
  iso_url                   = "https://cloud.debian.org/images/cloud/bookworm/20240102-1614/debian-12-genericcloud-amd64-20240102-1614.qcow2"
  net_device                = "virtio-net"
  output_directory          = "artifacts_tests"
  cd_files                  = ["./user-data", "./meta-data"]
  cd_label                  = "CIDATA"
  qemuargs                  = [["-m", "16384M"], ["-smp", "8"]]
  communicator              = "ssh"
  host_port_min             = 2222
  host_port_max             = 2299
  shutdown_command          = "sudo shutdown -P now"
  shutdown_timeout          = "10s"
  ssh_private_key_file      = "./packer_key"
  ssh_clear_authorized_keys = true
  ssh_username              = "root"
  ssh_timeout               = "20s"
}

build {
  sources = ["source.qemu.example"]
  provisioner "shell" {
    inline = [
      "apt-get update",
      "apt-get install python3",
      "apt-get autoclean",
      "apt-get clean"
    ]
  }
}
```

With this you should be able to reproduce build

`$ packer version`

```
Packer v1.10.0
```

Comment: This is one great answer. Thank you very much. I stumbled on something similar for raspberry: https://github.com/mkaczanowski/packer-builder-arm/blob/master/boards/raspberry-pi-4/ubuntu_server_20.04_arm64.json
But never got it work. Thanks a lot